# Showing that a two-dimensional Euclidean CFT ghost action is hermitian

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, complex-numbers, ghosts

At the end of chapter 6 in Polchinski's String Theory book he says that the $c$ ghost is anti-hermitian. With that information, I tried to show that the action for the $bc$ system

\begin{equation}
S= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d^2z \; b \bar{\partial}c
\end{equation}

is hermitian. We have

$$S^\dagger = \int d^2 z \;(b \bar{\partial}c)^\dagger = \int d^2 z\;  - \partial c b = \int d^2 z \; b \partial c, $$
which is not the same as the original action that I started with because $\bar{\partial}^\dagger = \partial$.

Question: How do I show that the action for the $bc$ system is hermitian? Do I need to add the antiholomorphic part and define $b^\dagger = \tilde{b}$ and $c^\dagger = - \tilde{c}$? But this seems wrong to me because $b$ and $c$ should be functions of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ for the action to make sense.

I am very confused and, for sure, missing something basic. I would like a very detailed answer so that I can learn how to take the hermitian conjugate in general for a Euclidean two-dimensional CFT.

Comment: hint: anti-hermitian in Lorentzian signature (which in Euclidean signature is furnished by the Euclidean adjoint which does not conjugate z)